# GUI tools for PostgreSQL/PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, tilemill, gui

as a cartographer I work with TileMill to visualize geodata. I installed a local PostgreSQL server with PostGIS and osm2pgsql. Everything works fine.

Anyhow, I am new to working with servers and the command line approach. 
So, in learning the basics of database management, some GUI tool would be of great help. 
Could I for example safely run the PgAdmin app next to the PostgrSQL installation (http://postgresapp.com/) on my Mac OS X Mavericks?

Any suggestions most welcome.

Comment: yes you can use pgadmin and postgres simultaneously.

Comment: Use pgadmin. On many platforms (eg windows) it is even part of the default postgresql install.

Comment: On the Mac it's just a little app to get the server running. And it provides a link to the command line.

Comment: I got pgAdmin running now alongside Postgres. It is a good couple: learning the database structure thru the GUI and practising the commands in the Terminal.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A great solution is to use [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) as a GUI for PostGIS.

QGIS is a fully-functional GIS (I prefer to think of it actually as a meta-GIS given that it is built on many GIS packages). It has built-in support to connect to PostGIS and therefore gives you all the tools needed to view, edit and create maps from your data.

Comment: I work with QGIS but I was not aware of the PostGIS functions. Thanks for the advice & have a good day.