# How to upgrade pgAdmin 4 in Windows?

Tags: installation, windows, pgadmin-4, upgrade

A new version of pgAdmin 4 is [released](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/3.x/release_notes.html) almost every month. I wonder what is the correct way to upgrade a newer version of it?

Is it necessary to uninstall the older version first and install the new one latter? Or will the installer from the newest version overwrite the old ones without fragmenting files in the system?

I could not find the answer in pgadmin.org website or other places as well.

<sub>I believe this is on-topic as discussed in GIS Meta: [Are software installation questions on topic?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4490/are-software-installation-questions-on-topic) Besides providing great support for PostgreSQL, pgAdmin 4 now even has a geometry viewer (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79901/what-spatially-aware-gui-administration-softwares-exist-for-postgresql-postgis/300190#300190)).</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**:

After upgrading to version 5.2, it created a new folder 'v5' within 'Program Files\pgAdmin 4' (instead of overwriting 'v4'). So, I manually uninstalled pgAdmin 4 'v4' (through Windows 'Control Panel') and then, deleted the remaining 'v4' folder. My server connections and master password kept unaltered in the new version.

---

Original answer:

In Windows, I have been using and upgrading pgAdmin 4 since version 3.1. Now, have just upgraded to 4.22 version (mai/2020).

What I do is just download the installer (see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/)) and run it. It will overwrite previous version. The server connection setups I had in previous versions are all kept when starting the new version as well.

Comment: If you get errors after installation, delete the folders under %appdata%\pgAdmin, you'll lost the stored connection though. But with new versions old files in that directory may cause errors.